# Load a model manually with EmberData

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an Ember app with a login form which returns the current user in JSON format after successful login.

Using `createRecord` sets the returned JSON attributes directly on the model. For instance, `is_private` becomes `user.is_private`, not `user.get('isPrivate')`?

How do I load the user model so that the attributes are set correctly and I don't have to re-fetch it using the id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supposedly, the official way to do this is using `adapter.load`, as [described in this thread](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/loading-sideloaded-data-received-through-a-websocket/905/2):

> **Loading Data**
>
> Previously, some features of the store, such as `load()`, assumed a
>   single adapter.
>
> If you want to load data from your backend without the application
>   asking for it (for example, through a WebSockets stream), use this
>   API:
>
> `store.adapterForType(App.Person).load(store, App.Person, payload);`
>
> This API will also handle sideloaded and embedded data. We plan to add
>   a more convenient version of this API in the future.

But unfortunately, it doesn't handle sideloaded data, despite what the documentation claims. I personally use something like the following, which is based on how `find(ID)` is implemented:

```
var id = json["person"]["id"];
var store = DS.get("defaultStore");
var adapter = store.adapterForType(App.Person);
adapter.didFindRecord(store, App.Person, json, id);
var person = App.Person.find(id);
```

Note that this code assumes JSON in the same format that `find(ID)` expects to receive from the server, as [documented in the RESTAdapter guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/):

```
{
  person: {
    id: 1,
    is_private: false,
    projects: [3]
  },
  projects: [
    { id: 3, name: "FooReader" }
  ]
}
```

This will apply any transformations you've configured using `keyForAttributeName` (such as mapping `is_private` to `isPrivate`), and it will handle sideloaded records. I'm not sure if this is a best practice, but it works quite well.

Comment: Thanks! I was close to `didFindRecord` but I'm not sure I fully knew what was going on with that method.

Comment: Hi. This turnaround works very well while I am populating a single record. How can I populate multiple records? For example:  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NNFVDYR0

Comment: And as far as I can tell this no longer works in ember-data 1.0.0-beta.3 I was using this in ember-data 0.14 but I ended up using the answer andorov gave with 1.0.0-beta.3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18948134/1477165

Comment: In more recent versions of ember/ember-data this is now achieved using `store.pushPayload` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35356634/621809).

Answer (score 9):

As of a few days ago in ember data 1.0 beta you can use `pushPayload` to load data directly into the store.  For example if you get data pushed to your app through WebSockets (we use the Heroku add-on [Pusher](https://addons.heroku.com/pusher)).  You can call it on the store ([source)](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/a58ec28c927bcb246344be818ee0214a6dfe6aef/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1140) directly and it will pass it through the appropriate serializer:

```
var postsJSON = {
  posts: [
    {id: 1, post_title: "Great post"}
  ]
}

this.store.pushPayload('post',postsJSON)
```

NOTE that it will not currently load a singular object (ie `post: {id: 1, post_title:"First!"}`) - you need to format it as plural with an array.

`DS.RESTSerializer` has `pushPayload` as well ([source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/2287353bbcac132307ca72b128988fcbca79eab0/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L507)), in which case you need to pass it the store instead.

I highly encourage reading the source code before using, as it looks like the implementation of it will be revisited.

Comment: I fully expect this to break sometime, but at least it is something that works for now. I hope it doesn't. I did have to turn my json into a plural with an array for just the single object.

Comment: This was posted over a year ago and still works perfectly today, I'm guess that this is here to stay.

Answer (score 5):

how about `store.push('user', userJSON)`?

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/#toc_pushing-records

Answer (score 0):

All answers above did not work for me.
What only worked for me was:

```
this.store.buildRecord(this.store.modelFor('person'), data.id, data)
```