# How to convert JSON to store object?

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I have a JSON object from my Spring backend. How do I create a data object in my Ember application store?

I tried:

```
createObject() {
  var _this = this;
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/object/getCard?id=24').then(function(response) {
     _this.store.createRecord('cards/object/card', response);
  });
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "id":24,
  "fullName":"qwerty",
  "form":"zzzzzzzzzzzz",
  "leader": {
    "id":23,
    "fullName":"testName test",
    "email":"emailTest"
  }
}
```

I have a model in Ember app

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  fullName: DS.attr('String'),
  form: DS.attr('String'),
  leader: DS.belongsTo('contact', { async: true })
}
```

And contact model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  fullName: DS.attr('String'),
  email: DS.attr('String')
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`store.pushPayload`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload) instead, since the record already exists in the backend:

```
createObject() {
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/object/getCard?id=24').then((response) => {
     this.store.pushPayload(response);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have an error: "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Expected an object in the 'data' property in a call to 'push' for undefined, but was undefined".

Comment: Hm, you need to match the format of your JSON to the format the adapter you're using expects. See [Model Maker](http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/) for a reference. You might need to [implement a custom serializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/models/customizing-serializers/).